# Regex python rule based eliza implementation

Tags: python, regex, nlp

```
import random
import re

rules=[["(.*)hello(.*)",["Hi there. Please state your problem"]],
           ["(.*)name(.*)",["Great, good to know","I am not interested 
        in names"]],
  ["(.*)sorry(.*)",["please don't apologize","Apologies are not necessary","What feelings you have when you apologize?"]],
 ["(.*)",["Very interesting","I am not sure I understand you fully","Please continue",
         "Do you feel strongly about discussing such things?","\\2"]]]

grammar = {
"am": "are",
"was": "were",
"i": "you",
"i'd": "you would",
"i've": "you have",
"i'll": "you will",
"my": "your",
"are": "am",
"you've": "I have",
"you'll": "I will",
"your": "my",
"yours": "mine",
"you": "me",
"me": "you"
}

def correction(word):
character=word.lower().split()
for i, j in enumerate(character):
    if j in grammar:
        character[i]=grammar[j]
return " ".join(character)

def test(sentence):
for pattern, message in rules:
    match=re.match(pattern,sentence.rstrip(".!"))
    if match:
        response = random.choice(message)
        temp = " " + correction(match.group())
        response2 = re.sub(r"\\2",temp,response)
        return response2
      else:
        recall=random.choice(message)
        return recall



while True:
sentence =input("You: ")
print("JBot: " + test(sentence))

    if sentence == "quit":
    break
```

In this simple `eliza` implementation, there is a list called rule with a set of patterns and corresponding responses. This code is supposed to get a random response if a pattern is matched or if anything else is entered that is not on the rule(last rule).

Code right now only outputs, `"Hi, there. Please state your problem"` for all input statements. Any help why this is happening??

If you input a sentence that is matched in the rule , then it will reply with corresponding response. suppose for a rule like following: `'(.*)`are like`(.*)'`, ["What resembelence do you see between `{0}` and `{1}`?"]] , if the input is `"Cats are like dogs"` response should be something like, What resemblance do you see between cats and dogs? So it takes a group from the match and places in the respective response.

Comment: Could you add some explanations about the behavior you expect of your code?

Comment: Very basic question answering behavior. If you input a sentence that is matched in the rule , then it will reply with corresponding response.  suppose for a rule like following: '(.*)are like(.*)',
     ["What resembelence do you see between {0} and {1}?"]] , if the input is "Cats are like dogs" response should be something like, What resembelence do you see between cats and dogs? So it takes a group from the match and places in the respective response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code and this should work as expected now:

**Notes:**

- The `else` in the loop of the `test` function would quit the loop at each iteration, therefore you will not be able to browse all the rules, grammar. I have put it after the `for`, this will force first the check of each rule before going for a default randomly selected answer.

Code:

```
import random
import re

rules=[["(.*)hello(.*)",["Hi there. Please state your problem"]],
           ["(.*)name(.*)",["Great, good to know","I am not interested in names"]],
  ["(.*)sorry(.*)",["please don't apologize","Apologies are not necessary","What feelings you have when you apologize?"]],
 ["(.*)",["Very interesting","I am not sure I understand you fully","Please continue",
         "Do you feel strongly about discussing such things?","\\2"]]]

grammar = {
"am": "are",
"was": "were",
"i": "you",
"i'd": "you would",
"i've": "you have",
"i'll": "you will",
"my": "your",
"are": "am",
"you've": "I have",
"you'll": "I will",
"your": "my",
"yours": "mine",
"you": "me",
"me": "you"
}

def correction(word):
  character=word.lower().split()
  for i, j in enumerate(character):
      if j in grammar:
          character[i]=grammar[j]
  return " ".join(character)

def test(sentence):
  for pattern, message in rules:
      match=re.match(pattern,sentence.rstrip(".!"))
      if match:
          response = random.choice(message)
          temp = " " + correction(match.group())
          response2 = re.sub(r"\\2",temp,response)
          return response2
  recall=random.choice(random.choice([r[1] for r in rules]))
  return recall



while True:
  sentence =input("You: ")
  print("JBot: " + test(sentence))
  if sentence == "quit":
        break
```

**Output:**

```
You: 'hello'
JBot: Hi there. Please state your problem
You: "i don't have a name"
JBot: Great, good to know
You: "i am so sorry"
JBot: What feelings you have when you apologize?
You: "help me"
JBot: Do you feel strongly about discussing such things?
```

---

> ***The outputs are so funny it has literally made my day.***

---

Comment: Thank you very much!! Worked like charm, I knew i was going off the loop somewhere.P.S. Tried to be funny with the responses, i am glad you appreciated the humor